# Input:focus ~ label not working

Tags: html, css

Help I dunno how to fix this error on my css sheet, the part where input:focus ~ label is not working, I really dont know what's missing.Hope you can guys help me on this, I'm just new on web programming. I tried all the possible answers here and already googled possible answers but still not working.
The input username and password are mixed with the label.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Transparent Login Form Design </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">   
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Login</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" required="">
                </div>  
                <div class="inputBox">  
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" required="">
                </div>  
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
                <a href="#">Forget Password</a>    
            </form>


        </div>

 </body>
</html>

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(work.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 5px 15px 25px  rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 8px;     
}
.box h2
{
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
 }
.box .inputBox
{
    position: relative;
}      

.box .inputBox input
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.box .inputBox label
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:  #fff;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.box .inputBox input:focus ~ label
{
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label
{
    top: -20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #03a9f4;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.box .inputBox input:focus,
.box .inputBox input:valid
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #03a9f4;
}   

.box input[type="submit"]
{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #03a9f4;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
```

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for `~`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#general-sibling-combinators):

> 8.3.2. Subsequent-sibling combinator
>
> The subsequent-sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

In your example, element represented by the **second** sequence precedes the first.

---

CSS does not have a previous sibling combinator.